# Implementation of doGetTransaction()

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

In the `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager` class, the `getTransaction()` method calls `doGetTransaction()`. However, I cannot find the implementation of this method anywhere. Where is its implementation and what does it do?

Answer (score 1):

You will find the implementation of `doGetTransaction` in the concrete transaction manager implementation. If you have your transaction manager defined like this in your `spring-config.xml`:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
...
</bean>
```

you will get the concrete implementation of `doGetTransaction` in `HibernateTransactionManager`.

The `doGetTransaction` implementation will usually look for an existing transaction and store corresponding state in the returned transaction object.

This below statement is copied from [HibernateTransactionManager#doGetTransaction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTransactionManager.html#doGetTransaction%28%29) doc:

> The returned object will usually be specific to the concrete
>   transaction manager implementation, carrying corresponding transaction
>   state in a modifiable fashion. This object will be passed into the
>   other template methods (e.g. doBegin and doCommit), either directly or
>   as part of a DefaultTransactionStatus instance.
>
> The returned object should contain information about any existing
>   transaction, that is, a transaction that has already started before
>   the current getTransaction call on the transaction manager.
>   Consequently, a doGetTransaction implementation will usually look for
>   an existing transaction and store corresponding state in the returned
>   transaction object.

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer. But what is the inside code. Actually i want to know when the rollBack variable is set true.

Comment: sorry.. i don't know that. But i think that is a very specific implementation detail. If you are using Spring transaction management, you can define your transaction boundaries, when to rollback, when not to rollback without knowing that.